# Is getting more than 300 backlinks from a site OK for SEO?

Tags: seo, links, backlinks

I once mentioned my site on a site and now after 2 months I see more than 300 links to my site from that site according to Google Webmaster Tools.

All the links pointing to my root domain. Is this good? Is there anything to worry about?

Answer (score 1):

Generally this is not something to worry about. I am not sure what site is linking to you, it could be a toxic site (definition below). There are many scraper sites (performance sites that scrape Alexa data or keyword sites are the norm) out there that link to the domain root and they are not toxic. They just do not have any value. I have one that has just over 1900 links to my domain root. Yikes! But it is not a toxic site, meaning penalized or soon to be or likely in the near future. If this is the case for you, do not panic. All is fine. 300 is a relatively small number.

Comment: 300 is a relatively small number and not toxic for a site with a lot of backlinks. It's different for a new site with almost 0 backlinks.

Comment: Thanks for relieving me.. Site linking is a blog with good number of posts betatutorials.com